# Different effect of bold tag in IE and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, bold

I have surrounded the text with bold tag, It renders differently in IE and Chrome.

IE image  --> 
[image]

Chrome image -->
[image]

Can anyone please figure out what can be done here?

Thanks

Comment: What font is that? And what font-size?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Font is `Arial Narrow` and size is `16px`. Sorry for being late.

Comment: If you're concerned about having it appear the same way in different places, maybe you should not be using HTML at all. It is not meant to code presentation, nor is the web about showing it the same way everywhere. People can (and, in fact, did, below) *explain* what is going on, now even if you can conceive some dirty hack to make it look the same, I doubt it's worth it, you'd only be "fixing" (if you even manage to) it for *two* rendering engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both browsers have **a different rendering/layout engine**, the results could most likely different.

- IE  8 uses [Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) 4.0
- Chrome uses [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) 53n.##

It is **a matter of taste and applied experience** of the developers on both sides that delivers **a different interpretation** on how to render fonts (and pictures, and HTML etc...)

But in most cases, [it does not matter](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) ;).

[More stuff here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines) and [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200410/styling_even_more_form_controls/)

Answer (score 2):

IE and Chrome render `<b>` tag differently usually due to the browsers default CSS and how the engine decides to render it a fix to get them close to the same would be to use css.

```
<b id="example">Time</b>

#example {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:20px;
}
```

However in truth you will have to expect some differences in appearance on each browser only you can decide what is an acceptable difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<strong>` instead. It may be more consistent.
Also, make sure the font is the same size in each browser? Is it explciitly set?

Apart from that, Chrome and IE render things differently.
IE may make text wider, using ClearType.

There's a discussion about disabling ClearType here: [IE8: Disable cleartype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031531/ie8-disable-cleartype)

Comment: `<strong>` isn't really meant for that - here's a good read on [`<strong>` vs `<b>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649305/alternative-to-the-html-bold-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Short of cutting all your text as images, there's nothing you can do about this. Rendering engines, installed fonts, ClearType tuning/disabling, user preferences, etc. will all conspire against you when it comes to web typography.