# Embedded youtube has blurried my fonts. I want to know what font is that

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here are two fonts that are on my page. The top one is being displayed after I have embedded youtube video in my site, the bottom one is the default one. I want to know what font is this top one, because I would love to use it as the default one. How can I check it? Inspecting this element gives me nothing, because chrome says this is the default one (when clearly it is different).

[image]

Comment: Purely a guess: is it possible one is being rendered with [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx) and the other is not?

Comment: Yes. It looks just like cleartype. But how can I add this feature to my site?

Comment: Again, not a typography expert, but my guess is that's generally in the hands of the end user. [Here's a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031531/ie8-disable-cleartype) that shows how Cleartype might be disabled. Forcing it on? I'm guessing that is not possible.

Comment: @BobKaufman: Thanks for input, but it is possible. Why I know this? Because with youtube embedded, half of the text on my page looks like the top button (blurried), and half is not. So it must be possible, the question is how. :)

Comment: A reasonable assumption. [Here's a possibly relevant article](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/). I haven't read through the whole thing, but it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @BobKaufman: Well, this is weird, but that top font is exact same font, but with opacity set to 0.9. Anyways your link has helped, if you want, go make a response to that and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Strange problem - for me it looks like it's the same font but with applied text shadow css styling.

Something like this:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
```

Try to apply this to your webpage. This should stop all text shadows if defined.

```
* {
   text-shadow: none !important;
}
```